# Corda - setting up multiple user accounts in a single node

Tags: corda

Can you please suggest the workaround to set-up multiple user accounts in a single node. I have a Bank node where I need to set-up multiple accounts for the customers of the bank. Is this feature added in Corda

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported as of Corda 3.

However, it is commonly requested, and is discussed as a potential future Corda feature in Mike Hearn's talk The Future Of Corda, here: https://www.r3.com/miscellaneous/cordacon/.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sushil multiple user accounts in a single node can now be setup using the [accounts-sdk](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md) feature released with Corda 4.3.